# How to troubleshoot a white flash between page loads

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis

I'm working on a website, and it flashes a white screen between page loads, every time I click a link. I've read a lot of other posts on similar issues, but each scenario looks to be different. How do I best go about troubleshooting where this flash is coming from?

The site is using WordPress, custom built from the Genesis Child Sample theme. I'm not greatly versed in the Inspector tool. Anything I should be focusing on in reviewing/testing?

Comment: A white flash occurs for many reasons. First, if you have Google Optimize enabled, that is a common issue and they have a fix for it if you search for it. Second, a slow server will inevitably lead to a slow repaint which defaults to the browser’s default of white. Third, if you have a giant wrapper element that is delaying the paint of “the body” this will delay. Fourth, but not last, if you depend too much on JS and CSS, that can cause a delay.  Okay, one more, fonts if not queued properly can cause a white flash

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaas - I appreciate your help. I'll look into these points you mention.

Answer (score 0):

This issue ended up coming from an animation I was unaware of on the .site-container. I removed this CSS, and the issue was resolved.